# Eloquent - Prevent Deletion of data if foreign key has rows - Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys

I know that I can restrict deletion of foreign key data with this in the migration. Example

```
$table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('restrict')->onUpdate('cascade');
```

Trying to delete a category with eloquent will result in mysql errors if a child in the foreign key exists.

How do i capture this error in eloquent and present it to the user

Comment: try to var_dump your delete method, I hope you will get the error

Comment: I dont want to view the error I want to catch it maybe..Can you wrap the eloquent delete method in a try catch?

Comment: yes, you can wrap in try catch

Answer (score 6):

I finally Came up with this

```
try {
     $category->delete();
    } 
catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {

        if($e->getCode() == "23000"){ //23000 is sql code for integrity constraint violation
            // return error to user here
        }
    }
```